# Where is the bin directory in Hadoop project dir?

Tags: hadoop

I have been following the official as well as DigitalOcean's documentation(tutorial) but I could not follow their lead. Each of them suggests editing a file an running the Hadoop after editing:
`etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` in the dist directory.

I am unable to find such a file in the whole extracted dir from the latest stable release as well a release of 2.7.7

Where is the `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

The paths in the guide may or may not represent the actual bundle packaging. You should run `find` and see the results from the tar.